# Outlook 2016 Search results does not display correctly

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I do a search in Outlook the column that should show who the email is From is blank, and all emails found are in bold to indicate it is unread.

[image: Image1]

However when I specify either to search from Subfolders, All Mailboxes, or All Outlook Items, it works.  Only Current Folder and Current Mailbox it does not work correctly for.

[image: Image2]

I have tried:

- Repairing office
- Repairing pst (using SCANPST.exe)
- Changeing views in the search result
- Disabling all add-ins
- Used safe mode
- The latest Office updates are installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was reported by many users and there was a known issue that users are unable to view the name of the sender within search results for the Outlook client.

Office 365 admin can check details on the Office 365 Health Dashboard. According to the report, we estimate that the deployment process should complete within the next 24 hours based on current progress.

Please refer to the this thread in Technet forum:[From Field Blank During Searches](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/236aaf50-24fb-4cca-abab-43751c73c4f7/from-field-blank-during-searches?forum=outlook) to see whether this is the case for you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  The issue seems to have automatically been fixed for me.

Comment: Yes. I just check the status. It writes "Final status: We've confirmed that the deployment is complete and impact has been remediated."